# Diferenciar View acessada por um ContextMenu reutilizado em várias Views

Tags: java, android, context-menu

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo para Android no qual tenho duas imagens em uma tela, cliente e seu veiculo.

Eu quero mostrar um menu ao dar um click longo em ambas as imagens e até ai tudo bem, ao clicar em ambos os *imageView* o mesmo menu é mostrado, porém, como eu faço para diferenciá-los no método *onContextItemSelected*?

Este é o código:

- Registrei para que mostre o menu nos dois imageView

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.tela_cliente_cadastrar);

      registerForContextMenu(helper.img_clienteClick());
      registerForContextMenu(helper.img_veiculoClick());
  ```

  ...
- Criei o menu

  ```
  @Override
  public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

      menu.setHeaderTitle("Opções");
      menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_TAKE_PHOTO, 0, "Take photo");
      menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_VIEW_PHOTO, 0, "View");
      menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_DEL_PHOTO, 0, "Delete");
  ```

  }

E é aqui que está o problema pois não consegui encontrar um meio para discernir um do outro:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case MENU_TAKE_PHOTO: {
            helper.startCameraForClient();
            //or helper.startCameraForVehicle();
        }
        case MENU_VIEW_PHOTO: {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FotoFullscreen.class);
            intent.putExtra("image", PHOTO_CLIENT);
            //OR intent.putExtra("imagem", PHOTO_VEHICLE);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
        case MENU_DEL_PHOTO: {

        }
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Pedro, o `ContextMenuItemInfo` do `MenuItem` não lhe retorna nada de útil para diferenciar as duas Views?

Comment: Há alguma maneiras de criar o mesmo menu e reutiliza-lo em várias ListViews?

Comment: @Wakim de facto o `ContextMenuItemInfo` do `MenuItem` tem tudo o que é necessário para diferenciar as duas `views`. Apesar da minha resposta resolver o problema, seria útil você responder também, porque a utilização do `ContextMenuItemInfo` é mais elegante.

Comment: @ramaral, eu estive fazendo uns testes aqui nesse meio tempo. No caso dele, o `ContextMenuInfo` sempre virá nulo. Somente se ele estivesse usando o `registerForContextMenu` em um `AdapterView`, o `ContextMenuInfo` seria uma subclasse de `AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo` e no `getMenuInfo` viria uma instância que teria a informação exata da `View` que foi clicada. Mas para essa situação, acho que a sua solução é a mais adequada de fato.

Comment: @Wakim É verdade, já faz algum tempo que não programo em Android! Foi procurar em código que já fiz e já utilizei os dois métodos: `ContextMenuInfo` quando é uma `ListView` e este, o da minha resposta, quando não é.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No método `onCreateContextMenu` é passado a `view` que requisitou a criação do menu assim, em função dessa `view`, você pode inicializar uma variável que indicará qual a imagem que foi clicada.

```
private int imagemClicadaId;
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    imagemClicadaId = v.getId();
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Opções");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_TAKE_PHOTO, 0, "Take photo");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_VIEW_PHOTO, 0, "View");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_DEL_PHOTO, 0, "Delete");
}
```

No método `onContextItemSelected` utilize `imagemClicada` para actuar de acordo com o que pretende fazer em cada caso.

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case MENU_TAKE_PHOTO: {
            if(imageClicadaId == R.id.imagemCliente){
                helper.startCameraForClient();
            }
            else{ 
                helper.startCameraForVehicle();
            }
        }
        case MENU_VIEW_PHOTO: {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FotoFullscreen.class);
            if(imageClicadaId == R.id.imagemCliente){
                intent.putExtra("image", PHOTO_CLIENT);
            }
            else{
                intent.putExtra("imagem", PHOTO_VEHICLE);
            }

            startActivity(intent);
        }
        case MENU_DEL_PHOTO: {

        }
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Era isso que eu precisava, muito obrigado.